# Whiy BigQuery return float value in scientific notation?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a column that stored the last update time in epoch time as a FLOAT value.

When I query for this column I get it as a scientific notation like this:

```
1.385627666E9
```

How can I get the value in plain format like this:

```
1385627666
```

I have tried to cast it in String but it is worst.

Comment: what language/library are you using? can you share the code?

Comment: It was directly in SQL in BigQuery

Comment: Then the problem is how numbers are shown in the web interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that to cast the value as an integer just works fine:

```
SELECT INTEGER(last_update) FROM my_table
```